# How to query server using UUIDs

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jpa

I have a project I am working on that uses UUIDs. Unfortunately, when I try to query my DB to check if a specific UUID exists it always returns false even if I can see it in it. To check that my program works fine I switched UUIDs to normal Long IDs and all works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

This is how I generate UUIDs in my Entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID uuid;
```

This is my logic check in my service class:

```
boolean exists = technologyRepository.existsByUuid(t.getUuid());
if (!exists) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Technology with id " + t.getUuid() + " does not exist." );
}
```

`exists` always returns false when using UUIDS

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Technology with id 61b78428-8bbf-4d84-997f-62e0484c21cc does not exist.`

this is the UUID stored in my DB:

`61b784288bbf4d84997f62e0484c21cc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

The following is the error message I get by running the query on my H2 server directly:

`Values of types "BINARY(255)" and "CHARACTER VARYING(32)" are not comparable; SQL statement: SELECT * FROM TECHNOLOGY WHERE UUID = '61b784288bbf4d84997f62e0484c21cc' [90110-214] 90110/90110`

Comment: What is the datatype in the table? My guess is BINARY(255) based on your "this is the UUID stored in my DB" statement. UUIDs are 16 bytes though, so binary(16) would be a better choice. Or, if that's not possible, varbinary(255) might work (so your db isn't storing all of the extra `00` bytes to fill out the fixed-width field). Also, what is your actual database backend? You've tagged it with sql-server which is for MSSQL, but that's not an error from MSSQL.

Comment: i use H2 as server, but just moved it to MariaDB and yes, it is indeed BINARY(255)

Answer (score 1):

in my case I used "String" for the field with UUID in the Java class mapping the table.
The column in the table on the database is a VARCHAR. It has worked ok for me.

```
  @Entity
  @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
  @Table(name = "TABLE_WITH_UUID")
  @NoArgsConstructor
  @AllArgsConstructor
  public class TableWithUuid implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  
  [... other fields ...]
  
  @Column
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String uuid;

  [... other fields ....]
```

The code to create the UUID is the following:

```
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    String uuidString = uuid.toString();
```

I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the parameter `columnDefinition = 'BINARY(16)` to the `@Column` annotation solved the issue

Comment: I'm glad that solved your issue. I'd still recommend reevaluating the data type in your actual database. binary(255) is storing an extra 255 - 16 = 239 bytes per row. That's a lot.